# ionic CI failed to sign apk

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I run this in ionic CI

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -dig
g SHA1 -keystore myname.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk myname
```

but I got an error of unable to open jar file: android-release-unsigned.apk

I also tried the full path it still show the same error. What's wrong?

Comment: if you are in windows try running cmd prompt as administrator, if you are in OSX or linxu use sudo before the command, so sudo jarsigner -verbose (ect)

Comment: @JessPatton it said illegal option -dig

Comment: are you running the jarsigner in the same folder as your keystore and apk? also are you in your sdk build tools folder as well?